# ggplot2 facet_grid arrange panels

Tags: r, layout, ggplot2

the following example creates a `ggplot` with the 4 panels "A", "B", "C", "D" in one row.

I figured out how to plot these 4 panels in one column. However, what still remains a mystery  is how to arrange the 4 panels so that "A" and "B" are in the first row and "C" and "D" are put in a separate (second) row?

Here's my code:

```
df <- data.frame(
x = rep(rep(1:10, each=10), 2),
y = rep(rep(1:10, 20), 2),
grid = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=100)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point() +
facet_grid(. ~ grid, scales = "free")
```

Comment: `facet_wrap` with `ncol = 2` maybe?

Comment: Great! I did not know of that option and tried to solve it using a grid1 and grid2 column and setting different values to NA but did not work out :-) facet_wrap, however, worked! thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=grid)) +
  facet_wrap(~ grid, scales = "free")
```

[image]